With Python, how to apply vector operations to a neighborhood in an n-D image?
I have a 3D image with vector components (i.e., a mapping from R3 to R3). My goal is to replace each vector with the vector of maximum norm within its 3x3x3 neighborhood.
This task is proving to be unexpectedly challenging. I attempted to use scipy.ndimage.generic_filter, but despite its name, this filter only handles scalar inputs and outputs. I also briefly explored skimage and numpy's sliding_window_view, but neither seemed to provide a straightforward solution.
What would be the correct way to implement this?
Here's what I ended up writing. It's not very elegant and pretty slow, but should help understand what I'm trying to do.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def max_norm_vector(data):
    """Return the vector with the maximum norm."""
    data = data.reshape(-1, 3)
    norms = np.linalg.norm(data, axis=-1)
    idx_max = np.argmax(norms)
    return data[idx_max]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load the image
    range_ = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
    x, y, z = np.meshgrid(range_, range_, range_, indexing='ij')
    data = 1 - (x ** 2)

    # Compute the gradient
    grad = np.gradient(data)
    grad = np.stack(grad, axis=-1)  # Stack gradients along a new last axis


    # grad = grad[:5, :5, :5, :]  # Crop the gradient for testing
    max_grad = np.zeros_like(grad)
    for i in range(1,grad.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(1,grad.shape[1]-1):
            for k in range(2,grad.shape[2]-1):
                max_grad[i, j, k] = max_norm_vector(grad[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2, k-1:k+2,:])

    # Visualization
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

    # Plot original data
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
    ax1.scatter(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel(), c=data.ravel(), cmap='viridis', alpha=0.5)
    ax1.set_title('Original Data')

    # Plot maximum gradient vectors
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')

    # Downsample for better performance
    step = 3
    x_down = x[::step, ::step, ::step]
    y_down = y[::step, ::step, ::step]
    z_down = z[::step, ::step, ::step]
    max_grad_down = max_grad[::step, ::step, ::step]

    ax2.quiver(x_down.ravel(), y_down.ravel(), z_down.ravel(),
               max_grad_down[:, :, :, 0].ravel(), max_grad_down[:, :, :, 1].ravel(), max_grad_down[:, :, :, 2].ravel(),
               length=0.1, color='red', alpha=0.7)
    ax2.set_title('Maximum Gradient Vectors')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


mre?

@Nin17 I can try, but is anything really unclear about my question?

well just image shapes, which axis for the norm, what you've tried with sliding_window_view and why it doesn't work etc...

The norm would be on the last axis. In general, I'm asking more for directions than a working example. I'm sure sliding_window_view would work, but it's not nice to work with, in particular it doesn't handle boundary conditions. I was hoping an expert could point me to a better way.

@christoph-rackwitz, why did you remove the scikit-image tag? It's a likely candidate for a solution.

there you go. I could work up a solution involving none of those but now I'm afraid I might miss the point of what you need done. could you provide any code at all please? or dummy sample data? or a type definition? something?

what did you try specifically? you say "neither seemed to provide a straightforward solution." so you seem to want a straightforward solution too. I wouldn't want to present something that falls short. could you perhaps show what isn't a straightforward solution?

could you please confirm or correct: do you consider "maximum norm" over elements v1, v2 in R3 to be v1 if |v1|>=|v2|, v2 otherwise, where |.| is L2 norm? or do you mean to involve the L_{inv} norm?

and how would you like boundary conditions to be handled?

if you want to reach a wider audience, I would suggest replacing [tag:scikit-image] (550 watchers) with [tag:image-processing] (11.3k watchers)... unless you don't consider the problem to be image processing.

TBH I'm surprised that ndimage.generic_filter does not cut it, I'd expect it to be the right tool for the job. Consider opening a scipy issue with an MRE

Thanks all for the constructive comments! I've added an MRE. I'm fine with the current solution, TBH. I was just surprised there wasn't something more elegant, using something like ndimage.generic_filter.

DIPlib has this function implemented: dip.SelectionFilter().
This is how you'd use it:
grad = ...  # OP's grad array
norm = dip.Norm(grad)
out = dip.SelectionFilter(grad, norm, dip.Kernel(3, "rectangular"), mode="maximum")

You can cast the dip.Image object out to a NumPy array with np.asarray(out) (no copy of the data will be made). NumPy functions will accept the dip.Image object as input, but many functions in scikit-image expect the input array to have a .shape method or similar, which will fail if you don't do the cast explicitly.
Install the package with pip install diplib.
Disclaimer: I'm an author of DIPlib, but I didn't implement this function.

Thanks for your answer! Not sure I want to pull another dependency into my project, but it's good to have the option.


I also briefly explored skimage and numpy's sliding_window_view, but neither seemed to provide a straightforward solution.

It's not straightforward, but it can be done, and is then much faster than the original implementation (10x).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def original_implementation(grad):

    def max_norm_vector(data):
        """Return the vector with the maximum norm."""
        data = data.reshape(-1, 3)
        norms = np.linalg.norm(data, axis=-1)
        idx_max = np.argmax(norms)
        return data[idx_max]

    max_grad = np.zeros_like(grad)
    for i in range(1,grad.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(1,grad.shape[1]-1):
            for k in range(1,grad.shape[2]-1):
                max_grad[i, j, k] = max_norm_vector(grad[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2, k-1:k+2,:])
    return max_grad


def implementation_with_strides(grad):
    # generate views over neighbourhoods
    kernel_shape = np.array((3, 3, 3))
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
        grad, kernel_shape, np.arange(len(kernel_shape)))
    # flatten over voxels and neighbourhoods
    reshaped = strided.reshape((-1, 3, np.prod(kernel_shape)))
    # find indices for maximum norm vectors
    norm = np.linalg.norm(reshaped, axis=1)
    indices = np.argmax(norm, axis=-1)
    # index, reshape and return
    output_shape = (*(grad.shape[:3] - kernel_shape + 1), 3)
    output = np.zeros_like(grad)
    output[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1] = reshaped[np.arange(len(indices)), :, indices].reshape(output_shape)
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    # Load the image
    range_ = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
    x, y, z = np.meshgrid(range_, range_, range_, indexing='ij')
    data = 1 - (x ** 2)

    # Compute the gradient
    grad = np.gradient(data)
    grad = np.stack(grad, axis=-1)  # Stack gradients along a new last axis

    tic = time.time()
    original_output = original_implementation(grad)
    toc = time.time()
    new_output = implementation_with_strides(grad)
    tac = time.time()

    print(np.all(np.isclose(original_output, new_output)))
    print(f"Runtime of original implementation {toc - tic:.3f}")
    print(f"Runtime of new implementation {tac - toc:.3f}")

# True
# Runtime of original implementation 0.221
# Runtime of new implementation 0.020

